# How to pass variable value to .filter()

Tags: javascript

The following code is taken from the reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
function isBigEnough(value) {
      return value >= 10;
    }

    var filtered = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44].filter(isBigEnough);
    // filtered is [12, 130, 44]
```

I want to know if I can dynamically change the value of `10` in the `return` line by passing in a variable. From the reference I cannot figure out how to do this. I want to call the same filter callback but pass in a unique value for a regex test.

So it would look something like:

```
function isBigEnough(value, num) {
      return value >= num;
    }
```

Comment: You can curry the function or partially apply it with `bind` like `.filter(isBigEnough.bind(null, num))`, just gotta flip the args.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way would be simply to use an anonymous function and close over the variable you want to use:

```
var minSize = 10;
var filtered = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44].filter( val => val >= minSize );
```

If you really wanted to keep a named function to call back to, you could partially apply a parameter with bind:

```
function isBigEnough(minSize, value) {
  return value >= minSize;
}

var filtered = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44].filter(isBigEnough.bind(null,10));
```

Here, bind will return a new function with the leftmost parameter bound to 10 (the first argument, the one that is null, is what gets passed as `this` to the function when being invoked).  So the parameter that filter passes in will show up as the second value in the callback.

Comment: I like this but what about passing a regex like this... (I get an error that `val` is not defined): `var filtered = words.filter(/\b\w{5}[.]/.test(val));`

Comment: You missed the arrow at the beginning (which is a type of ES6 anonymous function):  `var filtered = words.filter(val => /\b\w{5}[.]/.test(val))`

Comment: @MichaelRader Or the equivalent (in this case) ES5 and prior version: `var filtered = words.filter(function(val) { return /\b\w{5}[.]/.test(val);})`

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
function isBigEnough(num) {
  return function(value) {
    return value >= num;
  }
}
```

And then

```
[12, 5, 8, 130, 44].filter(isBigEnough(10));
```

How does this work?

- calling `isBigEnough(10)` returns an anonymous function
- then that anonymous function is passed to filter

Answer (score 4):

This should work.  The second argument (`10` in this case) gets passed as `this`.

```
function isBigEnough(value) {
    return value >= this;
}
var filtered = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44].filter(isBigEnough, 10);
```

Comment: That being said.  Even though this works, the other answers are probably more proper.

Comment: sorry I couldn't even get this to work. Thank you though.

Comment: I'm not sure why.  Here is a working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/zwmJ83WpTK4LQRVOcwx3?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

how about this (more generic) approach:

```
//argument order is chosen to be consistent through all functions, and readability when used:
var op = { //for operator
    eq: b => a => a === b,  //equal
    neq: b => a => a !== b, //not equal,
    gt: b => a => a > b,    //greater than
    lt: b => a => a < b,    //lower than
    gteq: b => a => a >= b,
    lteq: b => a => a <= b,

    //bonus, negating a function:
    not: fn => (...args) => !fn(...args) //to be used as `arr.filter( op.not(filterFn) )`
}
```

The shortcuts are common for these operators, besides that I think that the resulting code pretty readable and self-explaining

```
var filtered = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44].filter( op.gteq(10) );

//or:

//defining how to validate thew values
var isBigEnough = op.gteq(10);

//...

//the rest of the code only utilizes this function -> only 1 place to change
var filtered = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44].filter( isBigEnough );
```